# Trouble Setting Page Title with Unhead in Vue: Type Mismatch Warning

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, unheadvue

I'm attempting to update the document title using [Unhead](https://unhead.unjs.io/) in Vue, but I'm encountering a type mismatch warning in my IDE that I can't seem to resolve. According to the [Unhead documentation](https://unhead.unjs.io/setup/vue/best-practices) for Vue, I set up the title using the following code:

```js
import { ref } from 'vue';
const pageTitle = ref<string | undefined>(undefined);

useHead({
    title: () => pageTitle
});
```

However, this leads to the following warning::

> Type '() => Ref<string | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Title
> | Promise | undefined'.   Type '() => Ref<string | undefined>'
> is not assignable to type '() => Title'.ts(2322)

To update the `pageTitle` ref when the pet (reactive object) changes, I've tried the following:

```js
watch(() => pet.value?.name, () => {
    pageTitle.value = pet.value?.name;
});
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this type mismatch issue or a different approach to setting the page title dynamically using Unhead in Vue?

Comment: It's either `title` or `() => title.value` for a ref, `() => title` doesn't make sense in terms of vue reactivity

Comment: I had the same thought, but according to the documentation, they recommend `() => title`: https://unhead.unjs.io/setup/vue/best-practices#:~:text=useHead(%7B-,title%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20title,-%7D)

Comment: The example from the docs doesn't show that "title" is a ref, although this would make sense, also it's sketchy, "watch" snippet is incorrect either

Comment: So how do I supposed to use a ref, or even better, a computed property?

Comment: Like another doc shows, https://unhead.unjs.io/setup/vue/how-it-works. It's already mentioned in the previous comment, `useHead({ title: pageTitle })`

Comment: Then, the IDE complains like this:
```Type '() => Ref<string | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Title | Promise<Title> | undefined'.
  Type '() => Ref<string | undefined>' is not assignable to type '() => Title'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: You cited an error you'd get with  `title: () => pageTitle`, it doesn't differ from the one in the question. If it's not so, please provide a way to reproduce